# How to change buttons dynamically

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a XML file with a canvas and two linear layout, one up of the canvas and the other at the bottom.
I want to have four buttons at the top and the other at the bottom, when I clicked one, (play button) I would like that this linear changed the buttons.

Comment: "I have a XML file with a canvas " it doesnt make any sense

Comment: your reply doesn't make sense either :) please elaborate completely what are you looking for. Post your xml, post some images showing what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add views dynamically using the LinearLayout.addView() in combination with LinearLayout.removeView() and pass in the widgets that you want to add or remove.